# CoordinatorLayout - match_parent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

**Little, but annoying problem:**

I've made a tabbed `Activity`, where the tabs contain a `ListView`. However, if I set the `ViewPager`'s dimensions to `match_parent`, everything seems to be fine, **BUT**, at the bottom, the `ViewPager`'s egde goes out of the screen.

Like this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t20LV.png)

Result: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUvkk.png)

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                             tools:context="de.gymoth.goapp.vertretungsplan.VertretungsplanActivityNew">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

**Java:**

```
public class VertretungsplanActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {

private VertretungsplanFragment firstFragment;
private VertretungsplanFragment secondFragment;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vertretungsplan);

    firstFragment = VertretungsplanFragment.newInstance(0);
    secondFragment = VertretungsplanFragment.newInstance(1);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                return firstFragment;
            case 1:
                return secondFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "";
    }
}

public void setTabTitle(int index, CharSequence title) {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(index).setText(title);
}
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this? **Any help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `CoordinatorLayout` with `LinearLayout`, then it will work fine. I added sample code bellow.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Roshan's answer is good unless you will need the functionality of CoordinatorLayout.
In that case you can do a simple workaround:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Never ever opt for these sorts of workarounds. The actionBar need not be 48dp on devices and even if it were, the collapsingActionBar would create problems